# Obtain CpsScript instance in workflow-cps groovy code?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Currently coding a lot of groovy for very specific jenkins scenarios.

The problem is that I have to keep track of the current [`CpsScript`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsScript.html)-instance for the context (getting properties, the environment and so on) and its `invokeMethod` (workflow steps and the likes).

Currently this means I pass `this` in the pipeline groovy script onto my entry class and from there it's passed on to every class separately, which is **very annoying**.

The script instance is created by the `CpsFlowExecution` and stored within the `Continuable`-instance and the `CpsThreadGroup`, neither of which allow you to retrieve it.

Seems that `GlobalVariable` derived extensions receive it so that they have a context but I'm currently not knowledgeable enough to write my own extension to leverage that.

**So the question is:**

Does anyone know of a way to keep track of the `CpsScript`-instance that doesn't require me to pass it on to every new class I create? (Or alternatively: obtain it from anywhere - does this really need to be so hard?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continued looking into ways to accomplish this. Even wrote a jenkins plugin that provides an `cpsScript` global variable. Unfortunately you need the instance to provide a context for that call, so it's useless.

So as the "least bad solution"(tm) I created a class I called `ScriptContext` that I can use as a base class for my pipeline classes (It implements `Serializable`).

When you write your pipeline script you either pass it the `CpsScript` statically once:

```
ScriptContext.script = this
```

Or, if you derived from it (make sure to call `super()`):

```
new MyPipeline(this)
```

If your class is derived from the `ScriptContext` your work is done. Everything will work as though you didn't create a class but just used the automagic conversion. If you use any CpsScript-level functions besides println, you might want to add these in here as well.

Anywhere else you can just call `ScriptContext.script` to get the script instance.

The class code (removed most of the comments to keep it as short as possible):

```
package ...

import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.*

class ScriptContext implements Serializable {
    protected static CpsScript _script = null

    ScriptContext(CpsScript script = null) {
        if (!_script && script) {
            _script = script
        }
    }

    ScriptContext withScript(CpsScript script) {
        setScript(script)
        this
    }

    static void setScript(CpsScript script) {
        if (!_script && script) {
            _script = script
        }
    }

    static CpsScript getScript()
    {
        _script
    }

    // functions defined in CpsScript itself are not automatically found
    void println(what) {
        _script.println(what)
    }

    /**
     * For derived classes we provide missing method functionality by trying to 
     * invoke the method in script context
     */
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        if (!_script) {
            throw new GroovyRuntimeException('ScriptContext: No script instance available.')
        }
        return _script.invokeMethod(name, args)
    }

    /**
     * For derived classes we provide missing property functionality.
     * Note: Since it's sometimes unclear whether a property is an actual property or
     * just a function name without brackets, use evaluate for this instead of getProperty.
     * @param name
     * @param args
     * @return
     */
    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        if (!_script) {
            throw new GroovyRuntimeException('ScriptContext: No script instance available.')
        }
        _script.evaluate(name)
    }

    /**
     * Wrap in node if needed
     * @param body
     * @return
     */
    protected <V> V node(Closure<V> body) {
        if (_script.env.NODE_NAME != null) {
            // Already inside a node block.
            body()
        } else {
            _script.node {
                body()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to work around the fact that the script security plugin will not allow you to call `invokeMethod()` or `propertyMissing()` or don't you use the `ScriptContext` class as base class for anything defined in the `Jenkinsfile` or loaded using the load step?

Comment: I've opted to work with a global library instead of a folder library. The underlying code contains a ScriptContext based class per pipeline. Since a global library is trusted, the sandbox does not apply. Which is exactly the reason I did it like that.